# Is there an analytical solution to MLE of linear regression with non-normal(exponential) error term?

Tags: statistics, exponential-distribution, maximum-likelihood, linear-regression

I know that MLE of normal linear regression $y = k_1x_1+k_2x_2 + \epsilon, \epsilon\sim N(0,1)$ has a nice analytical solution. But what if

1. the error term is exponential distribution?
2. the error term is a distribution in exponential family and the mean linearly depends on $x_i$?

Comment: The likelihood function could be 0 everywhere due to positivity of $\epsilon$.  For example, if $y=-1$ on the four corners $(x_1,x_2)=(\pm 1,\pm 1)$.

Comment: Could you illustrate a bit more on the positivity part? I'm not sure why $N(0,1)$ doesn't have positivity. And what if there's only one variable $x_1$?

Comment: I mean if $\epsilon$ is exponentially distributed, then we must have $\epsilon>0$.  But if you sum the four corners you get $\sum\epsilon_i=-4$.